# Unable to sign in google using selenium using different account

Tags: python

I'm using selenium in python to automate gmail sign in. I'm only able to do it with the email id i used 1st to sign in. Trying to sign in using any other email throws the following error:

Couldn't sign you in
This browser or app may not be secure. Learn more
Try using a different browser. If you’re already using a supported browser, you can refresh your screen and try again to sign in.

I tried changing default gmail account for browser but that didn't.

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS:

Use [Seleniumwire](https://pypi.org/project/selenium-wire/) with [undetected browser v2](https://pypi.org/project/selenium-wire/#bot-detection)

> Note: put chromedriver in your sys path.

```
from seleniumwire.undetected_chromedriver.v2 import Chrome, ChromeOptions
import time

options = {}
chrome_options = ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--user-data-dir=hash')
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
# chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
browser = Chrome(seleniumwire_options=options, options=chrome_options)

browser.get('https://gmail.com')
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="identifierId"]').send_keys('your-email')
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="identifierNext"]/div/button').click()
time.sleep(5)
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="password"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/input').send_keys('you-password')
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="passwordNext"]/div/button').click()
```

In addition to this, selenium wire has many awesome features, check out Github [repository](https://github.com/wkeeling/selenium-wire)